# Azure Redis Cache Host Machine

Tags: azure, redis, azure-virtual-machine

I am currently playing with redis cache and need help to figure out whether to host it on a Linux machine or a Windows machine. I believe redis team does not officially support Windows. Thus the safer option goes to Linux.

But i prefer to use windows if there is a reliable implementation since i feel more comfortable with it.

Microsoft developed their own implementation of redis on 64bit windows server and claiming its production ready. What i need to know here is what they are using to host their Azure Redis Cache service. Do they trust their own implementation on windows or they went for the safer option.

**Note**: consuming azure redis cache as a service on the cloud is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i need to know here is what they are using to host their Azure
>   Redis Cache service.

I am using `Azure Redis Cache Service` under their `Basic` pricing plan. Based on the Server information retrieved using Redis commands, I believe they are hosting Redis Cache on a Windows platform.

[image]

Comment: I am no sure the "Branded" Azure Redis Cache services, but I am long known redis having Windows [fork](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis). Dip the documentation, but lazy to find more info. There is possible: Microsoft use WSL2, or they maintain a fork for Azure Redis Cache Services